# Facebook Permissions Request user Something Went Wrong error

Tags: facebook, permissions, request

I'm having some issues with allowing users to connect their accounts to my app.

Most users can do it fine, but some just comes back saying "Sorry, something went wrong." and this is for the same users all the time. I have two Facebook accounts, to test this, and one account is absolutely fine connecting, but another not really used account I use for testing, always fails.

For example, if Firefox is logged in to Facebook as User A, and IE is logged in to Facebook as User B, then copying the below link (obviously changing to the correct App id and the correct redirect_uri) works in Firefox, but in IE I get the "Something went wrong error"

http://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?_path=permissions.request&app_id=[MYAppID]&redirect_uri=[TheRedirectURL]&display=page&response_type=code&fbconnect=1&perms=publish_stream&from_login=1

Logging both out, and logging in each user into the other browser, the same user that worked before will work. So it's deffo not a browser issue, but down to the user surely, but no idea what.

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Did you accept the permissions on the account which doesn't work and then change those which are requested? Facebook doesn't allow for a reaccept dialogue if you change things. Try removing the app from that user's profile and revisit so you get the perms dialogue again.

Comment: HI Ben,

Thanks for the reply. With the account that doesn't work, I'm not even able to get to get to the accepting of permissions as the error occurs just after I've logged in, or straight away if I'm logged in.


I've also removed my app from the account that works, and logged out. I've also just tried the account that doesn't work, on a completely different machine, but alas the same thing.

Comment: It sounds like the problem is account or app related rather than machine/browser. Apologies if you've tried this but I couldn't work out if you had from your previous comment- If you log into Facebook with the non working account- not via your app or website etc just straight in on facebook.com. Dropdown (menu top right) -> Apps (menu left) Click edit- do those permissions shown match those requested from a fresh facebook account? http://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/ create a test user to trial it. Then try deleting the app using the x. Then see what happens.